# What tool can I use to sniff HTTP/HTTPS traffic?

Tags: software-rec, proxy, http, https

I'm looking for a command line tool that can intercept HTTP/HTTPS requests, extract information such as: (content, destination, etc.), perform various analysis tasks, and finally determine if the request should be dropped or not. Legal requests must than be forwarded to the application.

A tool that is similar in nature to [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), or [Snort](http://www.snort.org/), but operates at the HTTP level.

#### References

- [Intercept HTTP requests on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925135/intercept-http-requests-on-linux/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try [mitmproxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/).

- mitmproxy is an SSL-capable man-in-the-middle proxy for HTTP. It provides a console interface that allows traffic flows to be inspected and edited on the fly.
- mitmdump is the command-line version of mitmproxy, with the same functionality but without the user interface. Think tcpdump for HTTP.

#### Features

- Intercept HTTP requests and responses and modify them on the fly.
- Save complete HTTP conversations for later replay and analysis.
- Replay the client-side of an HTTP conversations.
- Replay HTTP responses of a previously recorded server.
- Reverse proxy mode to forward traffic to a specified server.
- Make scripted changes to HTTP traffic using Python.
- SSL certificates for interception are generated on the fly.

#### Screenshot

[image: sample ss]

#### Example

I setup an example [Jekyll Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) app which is listening on port 4000 on my localhost. To intercept it's traffic I'd do the following:

```
% mitmproxy --mode reverse:http://localhost:4000 -p 4001
```

Then connect to my mitmproxy on port 4001 from my web browser (`http://localhost:4001`), resulting in this in mitmproxy:

[image: ss of mitmproxy w/ JB #1]

You can then select any of the `GET` results to see the header info associated to that `GET`:

[image: ss of mitmproxy w/ JB #2]

#### References

- [mitmproxy documentation](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/mitmproxy.html)
- [How mitmproxy works](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/howmitmproxy.html) & [Modes of Operation](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/)

Answer (score 7):

#### `mitmproxy`/`mitmdump`

Equalivant to `tcpdump` for HTTPS is `mitmdump`. Here are the steps:

1. Install `mitmproxy` package (macOS: `brew install mitmproxy`).
2. Install [mitmproxy CA certificate](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/) by the following commands:

   ```
   $ mitmdump --mode reverse:http://mitm.it/ -p 8080
   $ wget --content-disposition http://localhost:8080/cert/pem
   $ open mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
   # Open, install and mark the certificate as trusted.
   ```

Now, here is the simple test on how to test reverse proxy:

1. Run: `mitmdump --mode reverse:https://example.com/ -p 4433`.
2. In another shell, run: `curl https://localhost:4433`.

   Now, you should see the page source and `mitmdump` command should produce the output like:

   ```
   Proxy server listening at http://*:4433
   [::1]:49446: clientconnect
   [::1]:49446: GET https://example.com/ HTTP/2.0
             << 200  1.24k
   [::1]:49446: clientdisconnect
   ```

For all traffic, just run: `mitmdump` or `mitmproxy`.

See: [`mitmproxy` docs page](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/) for more details.

---

#### Charles Proxy

If you're on macOS, there is also [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) app (GUI) which allows view all of the HTTP and SSL/HTTPS traffic between the hosts.

Answer (score 4):

For some situations, you can use a proxy that accepts incoming HTTP requests and makes outgoing HTTPS requests. As an example, I wanted to capture the traffic between `git` and github.com. I used [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/):

```
mitmproxy -s httpser.py
```

where `httpser.py` is:

```
def request(context, flow):
  flow.request.scheme = 'https'
  flow.request.port = 443
```

I then ran `git` like so:

```
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
git clone http://github.com/oxplot/difftr
```

Now using `wireshark` listening on `localhost`, one can capture the plain traffic. Without the proxy, github would redirect `git` to use HTTPS.